# LNK4086 warning and missing dll entrypoint in VS2008 asm build

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2008, build-process, masm, masm32

I tried to compile the following .asm file in VS2008 (as part of an empty Win32 dll project to which I added this single .asm file):

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

TRUE                        equ 1

.code
start:
DllEntry proc instance:DWORD, reason:DWORD, reserved:DWORD
    mov     eax, TRUE
    ret
DllEntry endp

CPUIDIsSupported proc uses ebx edx        
    mov  eax, 0

    pushfd
    pop  eax                    ; Get EFLAGS to EAX
    mov  ecx, eax               ; Preserve it in ECX

    xor  eax, 200000h           ; Check if CPUID bit can toggle
    push eax
    popfd                       ; Restore the modified EAX
                                ; to EFLAGS

    pushfd                      ; Get the EFLAGS again
    pop  ebx                    ; to EBX
    xor  eax, ebx               ; Has it toggled?
    and  eax, 200000h
    jnz  __not_supported        ; No? CPUID is not supported

    mov  eax, 1
    jmp  _ciis_ret_             ; Yes? CPUID is supported

    __not_supported:
    xor  eax, eax

    _ciis_ret_:
    push ecx                    ; Restore the original EFLAGS
    popfd

    ret
CPUIDIsSupported endp

.586
__cpuid proc stdcall public uses ebx edi __funcNumber:dword, __eax:dword, __ebx:dword, __ecx:dword, __edx:dword

    ; Must be 80586 and above
    call    CPUIDIsSupported
    dec     eax
    jz      _cpuid_begin_

    ; No CPUID instruction
    xor     eax, eax
    jmp     _cpuid_ret_

    _cpuid_begin_:
    mov     eax, __funcNumber
    cpuid

    mov     edi, __eax
    mov     dword ptr [edi], eax
    mov     edi, __ecx
    mov     dword ptr [edi], ecx
    mov     edi, __edx
    mov     dword ptr [edi], edx
    mov     edi, __ebx
    mov     dword ptr [edi], ebx

    mov     eax, 1

    _cpuid_ret_:
    ret
__cpuid endp

end start
```

The code was originally posted [HERE](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/cvega/archive/2006/04/07/2658.aspx).

When I build I get a warning:

warning LNK4086: entrypoint '_start' is not __stdcall with 12 bytes of arguments; image may not run

However, a .dll is generated.

When trying to use that dll I get an exception because "Unable to find entrypoint CPUIDIsSupported in dll"

But now here is the kicker:

If I compile exactly the same asm file in MASM32, I still get the LNK4086 but the dll can be properly called.

I would like to include the asm file in my VS2008 solution and build it from there instead of having to use MASM32. Therefore I would like to know what I need to change about my build process in order to get a working dll. Also I am interested to hear how I can create a 64 bit version of the dll from within VS2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `end start` to `end DllEntry` should fix the issues. VS2008 has a much newer version of ML to the one included with MASM32 and it may be more strict with regards to the entry point.

`DllEntry` and `start` are actually the same point, which is why the code runs. I would guess that when the warning appears no entry point is actually specified in the PE header.